# Is it possible to release a variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, scope, declaration

I'm just curious...

Is it possible to release a variable in c#?

What I mean is, can you do something like this:

```
...
string x = "billy bob";

//release variable x somehow

string x = "some other string";

//release variable x somehow

int x = 329;
...
```

... so basically you are declaring the variable multiple times in the same scope.

If this isn't possible in c#, what languages is it possible in?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, besides the fact that reusing variables is confusing, why would you not just create a new variable?

Comment: You could do a "casting" operation of changing the type if you wanted to go the other way, e.g. take an int and convert the value to a string for writing to a file or some other output device.

Comment: It's nice to see some answers upvoted, but this is one of those "how to turn planks into sawdust" questions :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it with scopes (loose term; formally I believe this would be a declaration space), e.g. the following is perfectly legal C# within a method body:

```
{
    string x = "billy bob";    
}
{
    string x = "some other string";
}
{
    int x = 329;
}
```

I wouldn't advise writing code like this though, it makes it far too easy to get variables confused in a method. Better to use different, more descriptive names, or separate each block out into its own method.

Comment: legal but just plain nasty...*eye stab*

Answer (score 11):

No, this isn't possible in C# within the same scope - for which I'm very grateful. It sounds like a recipe for readability disaster. As Greg has shown, you can introduce your own scopes within a method solely for this purpose though.

I don't know which languages allow you to do this - weakly typed languages will often let you assign arbitrary values of course, but I don't know of a language which has explicit variable declarations *with type information* and also allows a redeclaration in the same scope.

You might want to read Eric Lippert's most recent blog post, which is [all about scope](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx). (If you don't already read Eric's blog, you might want to clear out a few days in your calendar and read all the back posts... or at least the ones since he joined the C# team. Prepare to have your mind blown repeatedly.)

Answer (score 2):

you can reuse a string:

```
string x = "billy bob";
x = "some other string";
```

Why would you want to do this?

Maybe you can do this:

```
object x = "billy bob"
x = "some other string";
x = 329;
```

Then cast it as you like?

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign variables, of course:

```
string s = "billy bob";
s = "something else";
```

You can't redeclare variables in the same scope:

```
// This is illegal:
string s = "billy bob";
string s = "foo"
```

Since Object is the root of the type system in .NET, you can do something like this:

```
object o = "billy bob";
o = "foo";
o = 5;
```